# Image Drag and Drop, Upload -- Only allow one image to be uploaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, drag-and-drop, image-uploading

I'm creating an image uploader that looks like this:
[image: Image Upload]

This is what I want to happen:

1. The total number of images that the user can upload is one. In other words, if the user tries to upload another image, the previous one gets deleted.
2. When the user drops an image into the gray area, it appears
3. When the user clicks upload image, it appears

I managed to get 2 and 3 working. See the code on codepen here:
http://codepen.io/aseelaldallal/pen/QdwYgv/

Here are my problems:

1. Say the user drops an image into the gray box (or clicks upload image). The image appears. Now, say he/she tries to drop another image on top of the first one. What should happen is that the first image gets deleted, and the new image appears. Unfortunately, this does NOT work.
2. Say the user drops an image into the gray box (or clicks upload image). The image appears. Now say the user clicks upload image and selects another image. Nothing happens. The original image is still there.

Here is my code (or just click the codepen link above):

HTML:

```
<div id="imageBorder" class="container">

  <div id="imageContainer">

    <div id="dropbox">
      <i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <p> Drop image here or click to upload</p>
    </div>

    <div id="preview" class="hidden">
    </div>

    <button id="fileSelect" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Upload Image</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

      var dropbox = document.getElementById("dropbox"),
          fileElem = document.getElementById("fileElem"),
          fileSelect = document.getElementById("fileSelect");

      fileSelect.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
          if (fileElem) {
              fileElem.click();
          }
      }, false);

      dropbox.addEventListener("dragenter", dragenter, false);
      dropbox.addEventListener("dragover", dragover, false);
      dropbox.addEventListener("drop", drop, false);
  });

function dragenter(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
}

function dragover(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
}

function drop(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    var dt = e.dataTransfer;
    var files = dt.files;
    handleFiles(files);
}

function handleFiles(files) {
    var file = files[0];
    var imageType = /^image\//;
    if (!imageType.test(file.type)) {
        alert("NOT AN IMAGE");
        return;
    }
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.classList.add("obj");
    img.file = file;
    img.height = $('#dropbox').height();
    img.width = $('#dropbox').width();
    $(dropbox).addClass('hidden');
    $(preview).removeClass('hidden');
    preview.appendChild(img);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(aImg) {
        return function(e) {
            aImg.src = e.target.result;
        };
    })(img);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
}
```

CSS

```
#imageBorder {
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 300px;
  width: 550px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#imageContainer {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

#dropbox {
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: gray;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

#dropbox i {
  font-size: 6.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#dropbox p {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

#preview {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
```

I tried something as simple as adding

```
$(preview).empty() before preview.appendChild(img)... Didn't work .
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Small additional question: how do i get the img border radius to be 5px? I tried multiple methods, dont work :(

Comment: edit this question and add your new question about border radius or create a new question on this site.

Comment: Alright I managed to get the button working by adding:

 img.height = Math.max($('#dropbox').height(),$('#preview').height()) ;
    img.width = Math.max($('#dropbox').width(),$('#preview').width()) ;

    $(dropbox).addClass('hidden');
    $(preview).removeClass('hidden');
    $(preview).empty();

Still can't get drag and drop to work as specified in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hiding the dropbox which has the Event Listener on it, so that's why it's not working.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot comment as it was my first post and, apparently, I need a rep of 50

Comment: wasn't trying to 'trick the system' was trying to help. won't bother next time

Comment: thank you so much, i appreciate it ! And yes, that was the problem

Answer (score 1):

Alright I managed to get the button working by adding:

```
img.height = Math.max($('#dropbox').height(),$('#preview').height()) ;
img.width = Math.max($('#dropbox').width(),$('#preview').width()) ;

$(dropbox).addClass('hidden');
$(preview).removeClass('hidden');
$(preview).empty();
```

([codepen updated](http://codepen.io/aseelaldallal/pen/QdwYgv/))

I Still can't get drag and drop to work as specified in the question

Comment: This does not answer all questions in the original post.